# Running binaries via the apache cgi-bin

Tags: apache, fedora, cgi-bin

I am trying to run a binary via the common gateway interface (cgi-bin). But whenever I try to access *http://localhost/cgi-bin/binary* from my browser I get HTTP 500 Internal error, with the following log entry in /var/log

```
[Sat May 26 15:31:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP_HOST=localhost: binary
```

L.E.: This doesn't seem to happen if the cgi-bin object is a php script or python.

Comment: What are you trying to run in this manner? Is it actually a CGI binary?

Comment: Yes it was actually a binary generated from C, but I had no ideea how the output looked like, so I didn't realize that the error actually referred the start of output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure at the beginning of your code you output at least:

`Content-type: text/html\n\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
`#!/usr/pkg/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<BODY>\n";
print "<H1>Hello, world!</H1>\n";
print "</BODY>\n</HTML>";`
```

And make sure the 1st line `#!/usr/pkg/bin/perl` is also very important for it should fit your perl default directory.

You can use `$ whereis perl` to find the directory.